# Jquery check if value of one input is empty but other is not

Tags: jquery

I have got this code

```
<input id="WCOAB" type="text" Placeholder="Admins username"><input id="WFCOAB" class="IRFWTDIHMMADYBIHY"  type="text" Placeholder="Password">
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var D = document.getElementById("WCOAB");
    var X = document.getElementById("WFCOAB").value;
    $( "#UBDCTCESGBO" ).submit(function( event ) {
        if (D.value.length !=0 && X.value.length == 0) {
            alert("assa");
        };
    });
});
</script>
```

But it is not working.It works when i delete this && X.value.length == 0

Comment: You're setting the variables when the page is loaded, not after the user has entered anything.

Comment: @Barmar I should give variables after  $( "#UBDCTCESGBO" ).submit(function( event ) {?

Comment: Oh wait, I'm wrong. You're setting the variables to the elements, not the values.

Comment: Aren't you getting an error in the Javascript console for `X.value.length`, complaining something like "can't read property length of undefined"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting `X` to the value, not the element, like you do for `D`. Then when you use `X.value.length`, you're asking for the `value` property of a string, which doesn't exist. Change to:

```
var X = document.getElementById("WFCOAB");
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept your answer as soon as it will be possible

Answer (score 0):

Barmar was almost correct in his comment. You're getting a reference to the "WCOAB" element when the document is ready but You're getting the 'Value' of the "WFCOAB" element when the document is ready.

```
var X = document.getElementById("WFCOAB").value;
```

The value at that time is an empty string.

Am I the only person that is driven nuts by the use of "document.getElementById" when you're using jQuery. You do know that's the same as "$('#id')" right? If you're going to use jQuery then use jQuery.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#UBDCTCESGBO" ).submit(function( event ) {
        if ($('#WCOAB').val().length !=0 && $('#WFCOAB').val().length == 0) {
            alert("assa");
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: It bugs me, too, but it's a windmill I've stopped tilting at. I also prefer `== ""` rather than `.length = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is tagged jQuery, why not use .val() and check the strings brought back?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#UBDCTCESGBO" ).submit(function( event ) {
    if ($("#WCOAB").val() != '' && $("#WFCOAB").val() == '') {
        alert("assa");
    };
});
```

});

Comment: Actually, Greg Duncan's answer is the best one here

Comment: Because `D` and `X` are DOM elements, not jQuery objects. You need to change to `$(D).val()`.